# Is the Picard Group countable?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the Picard group of a (smooth, projective) variety always countable?

This seems likely but I have no idea if it's true.

If so, is the Picard group necessarily finitely generated?

Comment: The Néron–Severi Theorem asserts that $\mathrm{Pic}(X) / \mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ is finitely generated if $X$ is a proper smooth variety. So your second question is equivalent to: Is $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ finitely generated? But I don't think that this is true, because otherwise this Theorem would not consider the quotient. Also, I have found several papers whose results have the assumption that the Picard group is finitely generated. So probably it's not automatic. Interesting question by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Even for curves there is an entire variety which parametrizes $Pic^0$(X). It is called the jacobian variety. The jacobian is g dimensional (where g is the genus of the curve), so in particular if g > 0 and you are working over an uncountable field the picard group will be uncountable.

Answer (score 5):

It is noted [here](http://faculty.tcu.edu/richardson/Seminars/NL.pdf) and also in [math.SE/56356](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56356/geometrical-approaches-to-class-group-of-dedekind-rings) that the Picard group of a non-rational curve is not finitely generated.